# discord.js Editing a message and sleeping

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am very new to discord.js and wanted to know how I can edit a message and then sleep and then edit the message again so it doesn't cause extremely fast edits. I found this code and couldn't figure out what to do

```
message.channel.send("Beep").then((sentMessage) => sentMessage.edit("Boop!"))
```

Comment: the code you provided sends a message and edits it right after it's sent from what I see.  I don't know discord.js but with pure JS I would use setTimeout or setInterval.

Comment: If those are compatible with d.js, here's some quick info -------- setInterval will edit the message periodically, until the code stops. If you want to stop editing at some point, use the return value of the setInterval function and clear it (stop the interval) with clearInterval. --------- setTimeout, on the other hand, will wait some time, then edit the message and never edit it again (you can obviously still edit outside setTimeout, this is what the function itself does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by [`LercDsgn`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14362683/lercdsgn) in the comments, you can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to edit the message after a certain amount of time.

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) syntax:

> ```js
> setTimeout(function[, delay, arg1, arg2, ...]);
> setTimeout(function[, delay]);
> setTimeout(code[, delay]);
> ```

*Note that the delay is in ms. (3000ms = 3 seconds)*

---

```js
message.channel.send('Beep!').then(sentMessage => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        sentMessage.edit('Boop!')
    }, 3000);
})
```